# Wordpress custom table - get data out a foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

What I'm trying to achieve is:
I have a custom table with several rows. 
Every row is an item linked with a page (the "page" field of the row is the name of a page), so that when I open a page I get all the items linked to that page.

I managed to get the rows corresponding to the page name. But I don't know how to manage the array.

The idea is to pass the variables to a page template, in order to automatically fill is with the correct data.

```
global $wpdb;
$mytitle = get_the_title();

$results = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM wp_mytable WHERE page = %s', $mytitle));

$item-list = array();

foreach ($results as $r)
{
    $item-name = $r->name;
    $item-description = $r->desc;

    $item-list = "some html code with $item-name and $item-description";
}
```

In the page template I will just `<?php echo $item-list; ?>` in order to get all the items of that page.

But it doesn't seem to work.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you want to get multiple data then you should use `get_results()`
>   instead of `get_row()`.

Try this code.

```
global $wpdb;
$mytitle = get_the_title();

$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'mytable WHERE page = %s', $mytitle));

$item_list = '<ul>';
foreach ($results as $r)
{
    $item_name = $r->name;
    $item_description = $r->desc;
    $item_list .= '<li>' . $item_name . ' ' . $item_description . '</li>';
}
$item_list .='</ul>';
```

Now `$item_list` holds the list HTML so to use it by echoing it as `<?php echo $item_list; ?>`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm!